# SQSlistener not receiving messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

I am able to send messages to SQS queue from my springboot but not able to receive using sqslistener annotation, can someone help?

```
public void send(String message) {


    queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("test-queue", MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());
}

@SqsListener(value = "test-queue", deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER)
public void receive(String message)
{
    System.out.println("message: " + message);
}
```

I have verified send by goign to AWS console, i can see my messages in queue, but they are not coming to receive method.
config:

```
@Bean
public AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient()
{

    AmazonSQSAsyncClient amazonSQSAsyncClient= new AmazonSQSAsyncClient(amazonAWSCredentials());

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(amazonSqsEndpoint)) {
        amazonSQSAsyncClient.setEndpoint(amazonSqsEndpoint);

    }

}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory msgListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    msgListenerContainerFactory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSQSAsyncClient());
    return msgListenerContainerFactory;
}

@Bean
public QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    return new QueueMessagingTemplate(amazonSQSAsyncClient());
}

@Bean
public BasicAWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
    return new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is simply not enough information for anyone to help you. Have you turned on DEBUG logging? What do you see?

Comment: Hi, thats the strange part, there is no error, once i send the message there is nothing printed, message goes and sits in the queue and listener doesnt get the messages at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out i had a typo in the queue names in SQS console and my code, my bad.

Answer (score 6):

In my case i was missing an annotation `@EnableSqs` in config class

Answer (score 2):

Though it is late, it may help someone. In my case, I used gradle with these configuration

```
  implementation "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:2.3.0"
  implementation "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:2.3.0"
```

It doesn't work , below works perfectly for me:

```
compile "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging:2.3.0"
compile "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:2.3.0"
```

Comment: I had the same issue, it was working fine in mvn project but when I migrated it to gradle project it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the wrong region is specified. For some reason, sending didn't complain & pushed the message to the queue, but the listener is not getting called. Fixing the region in the application.yml file solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case QueueMessageHandler bean wasn't initialized.

In the documentation they are using maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
     <version>{spring-cloud-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But in my case I'm using gradle, and also require dependency:

```
implementation(platform("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:2.4.2"))
implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging")
implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure")
```

Or you could define QueueMessageHandler in your own config file

```
  @Bean
  public QueueMessageHandler queueMessageHandler(QueueMessageHandlerFactory factory) {
    return factory.createQueueMessageHandler();
  }
```