# Unable to read messages from SQS through Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

```
package com.example.aws.Springbootsqs.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.core.QueueMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.annotation.SqsListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class SQSController {
    
    Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(SQSController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private QueueMessagingTemplate queueMessagingTemplate;
    
    @Value("${cloud.aws.end-point.uri}")
    private String endPoint;

    
    @GetMapping("/put/{msg}")
    public void putMessagesToQueue(@PathVariable("msg") String message) {
        queueMessagingTemplate
        .send(endPoint, MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(message)
                .build());
        
    }
    
    @SqsListener("sqs-queue")
    public void loadMessagesFromQueue(String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    
    }
    
    
}
```

I am okay with pushing the messages to SQS but at the same time when i am reading and printing the messages the method is not being called and it is not printing anything from SQS and no error on console.

Any help will be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any messages on your queue?

See if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805823/sqslistener-not-receiving-messages

Comment: code is publishing the messages to queue and i can see in dashboard but not reading it back and ther eis nothing on console. it seems loadMessagesFromQueue method is not being called

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the SSO login method, The SQS listener does not currently support SSO login you have to refresh them either in the .aws folder or add ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY in the configuration file. It would be more beneficial if you could share your pom/build file I am not sure which build tool you are using.

Comment: Here is a quote from [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (paraphrased): _try not to answer questions which are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem._ You should post a comment asking the OP to state which login method he is using. Unfortunately, you don't have enough reputation to comment. That's just the way SO works. (I didn't make up the rules.) Please respect the rules and try to adhere to them.